# Writing to /etc/networking/interfaces at boot using sed/awk?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, awk

Newbie here,

I'm trying to write to an auto-generated `/etc/network/interfaces` file of a newely provisioned XEN Ubuntu (12.04/10.04/8.04) DomU server at boot time using (currently) `sed`.

The auto-generated file is formatted as below:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.88
    gateway 192.168.0.254
    network 255.255.255.255
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Using `sed`, I'm trying to alter lines 1 & 2, add a third line, remove the gateway and last two lines, and append four extra lines at the very end.

I'm currently stuck on adding the third line, as the script adds this line everytime it's run:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "1s/.*/auto lo eth0/" /tmp/interfaces
sed -i "2s/.*/iface lo inet loopback/" /tmp/interfaces
sed -i "2a\iface eth0 inet static" /tmp/interfaces
sed -i "s/auto lo//g" /tmp/interfaces
```

Is it possible to add the third line only if it doesn't exist using `sed` (or `awk`)?

Likewise, how can I delete the gateway and last two lines only if they don't exist?

I'm new to `sed`, so am wondering whether I should be looking at `awk` instead for achieving this?

Comment: Also, it might help to tell *why* you are doing this.

Comment: Sure.The Xen hosts (Dom0) provisioning system is not configuring the Ubuntu DomU's networking sufficiently on creation for bridge networking. So I'm trying to add the appropiate lines to the rc.local file so they get written at boot time, to enable public access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with sed:

```
sed -i -e '4{/iface eth0 inet static/! i\
    iface eth0 inet static
    }'
```

You can group commands with braces. The commands in the braces will only execute on the third line. The `i` insert command will only execute on the third line **and** if the third line doesn't match the string between slashes (the `!` after it tells it to execute when it doesn't match).

You can do the same to delete:

```
sed -i -e '3{/gateway/d}'
```

Here we delete the third line only if it contains the string `gateway`. You could probably be more generic and simply do:

```
sed -i -e '/gateway/d'
```

which will delete all lines that contain gateway, but maybe that's not what you want.

As for deleting the last lines, the easiest solution would be:

```
sed -i -e '${/auto lo/d;/iface lo inet loopback/d}'
sed -i -e '${/auto lo/d;/iface lo inet loopback/d}'
```

Where the `d` delete command is executed on the last line if it matches either `auto lo` or `iface lo inet loopback`. Executing it twice will delete the last two lines if they match the patterns.

If you want to add lines to the end of the file, you can do:

```
sed -i -e '$a\
newline1\
newline2\
newline3'
```

Or maybe only add them if the last line isn't a specific line:

```
sed -i -e '${/192\.168\.1\.1/!a\
newline1\
newline2\
newline3
}'
```

Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much for the answer as well as the thorough explaination on each function.

Comment: Quick question. Can I use the first sed command you quoted to add the extra four lines I need to add at the end?

Comment: You can. You can even do that in the same command, by making sure that a line ends with a backslash, sed will understand that you want to write a newline character and continue printing the next line. However, notice that the `i` command inserts text before the printed line, and the `a` command appends text after the printed line. If you want to add to the end, `a` is probably a better choice =)

Comment: Sorry. Tiny bit confused as to where I add the backslash. e.g. `sed -i -e '${/post-up route add 192.168.0.254 dev eth0/! a\
post-up route add 1192.168.0.254 dev eth0\
    }' /tmp/interfaces` Like so?

Comment: I guess the comment posting removed the formatting =). If your newlines were after the `a\`, and another after `etho0\`, then I think yes, that is how it's supposed to be. I'll try to give a better example: suppose you want to append three lines, `A`, `B`, and `C`. You would do: `a\<nl>A\<nl>B\<nl>C`, where `<nl>` represents an actual newline (enter).

Comment: Gosh, I'm even more confused now. Sorry. So to add lines `A`,`B`, and `C` at the very end of the file (or after `network 255.255.255.255` which is at the end now) if they don't already exist, I do the following? `sed -i -e '${/network 255.255.255.255/! a\<n1>A\<n1>B\<n1>C\ }' /tmp/interfaces` ? Thank you for being patient with me by the way.

Comment: Exactly! =) Just remember that the `<nl>` is an actual newline character. I've edited the post to include an example with proper formatting. Hopefully it looks a little more clear. =)

Comment: Aaah. I see. Can I intergrate this with your previous command so that the new lines aren't added again if they already exist? Thank you for all your help on this by the way. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so so much for all your help and patience. The script works perfectly now. :) + I have a better understanding of `sed` too.

Comment: Great! I'm happy to have helped =)

Answer (score 1):

This script do the job: https://github.com/JoeKuan/Network-Interfaces-Script

```
awk -f changeInterface.awk <interfaces file> <device=ethX> 
 <mode=(dhcp|static|manual)> [action=add|remove] 
 [address=<ip addr> netmask=<ip addr> <name=value> ...]
```